# Changing localhost addr to another addr via windows hosts file - Win 7

Tags: php, windows

When using programs such as EasyPHP, Wamp etc, I mostly access my scripts in the browser by prefixing localhost/ before the scriptname.

I have tried editing my hosts file located in **windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts** and adding the following

```
localhost lh
```

I was hoping to be able to now type only lh instead of localhost, but after a restart this does not seem to work.

Is this possible in just the hosts file?

I am using *windows 7 Professional*

Answer (score 0):

```
127.0.0.1 localhost lh
```

Seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is is possible. Alias to your NAT IP.

```
127.0.0.1 lh
```